# undefined reference to `forkpty'

Tags: c++, linker

So I'm developing my project in Eclipse in Ubuntu 10.04. I have the following lines of code:

```
#include <pty.h>

pid_t pid;
int master;

pid = forkpty(&master, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But when I try to build it within Eclipse, I get the error:

```
undefined reference to 'forkpty'
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: RTNM. Says "Link with -lutils".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need -lutil command line argument (to use libutil shared library).
For Eclipse:
http://zetcode.com/articles/eclipsecdevelopment/

Select Project Properties. Expand the C/C++ Build tab. Select settings. From the Tool Settings tab, expand the GCC C Linker option. Click on libraries. Add the /usr/lib/libutil.so  to the Libraries window. Notice, that this path may be different on your system.

Comment: @Hank You should "accept" this answer by clicking on the the checkmark symbol. That will give MK reputation points (a kind of karma system here at Stack Overflow). You can also upvote both of our answers as well.

Comment: I had to add util and not /usr/lib/libutil.so to get it working

Answer (score 7):

That's a linking error; you're missing the `util` library. Do this to build on the command line:

```
g++ myprogram.cpp -lutil
```

Eclipse should have project-level settings for listing the libraries to link against.

Comment: How would I do that in Eclipse?

Comment: @MK's answer seems to have the settings you need for Eclipse. Give that a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this issue when I was trying to install [**delegate**](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/)
So if you are trying to `make` delegate and getting error

```
undefined reference to `forkpty'
```

so edit `_-forkpty.c` file inside `maker` folder

`vim maker/_-forkpty.c` and add
`#include <util.h>`

```
make clean
make
```